# Regular Expressions to modify a url without splitting it in c#

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I had url like this 
http://xxxxxxxxxx.blogspot.com/?m=1A

I want to remove the last part of url ?m=1A with out splitting the url.

How can it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) as @Tom mentioned and replace the `String` with an empty one.

```
string value = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.blogspot.com/?m=1A";
value = value.Replace("?m=1A","");
```

or else

```
value = value.Replace("?m=1A",string.Empty);
```

Just have a look at this too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean by 'last part' the part after the question mark.

You could use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
string url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.blogspot.com/?m=1A";
Regex rgx = new Regex("^([^\?]+).*$");  // match all non-question mark characters from the start of line in $1
string result = rgx.Replace(url, "$1"); // replace the url with $1
```

btw: I did not test this snippet